# Fiware Instance Status Error

Tags: instance, status, fiware, fiware-poi

Hi I've been trying to try out the Fiware service.
I've setup an POI Instance in the Waterford Region.
I've followed the instructions and assigned a floating IP.
On the Instance page I have no IP address and an Status Error.
Under the security page -> Floating IP tab there is an IP address assigned.  The Instance is blank.  When I try and associate an IP to the instance i get a 400 error:

undefined. Cause: 400 Error
{"badRequest": {"message": "No nw_info cache associated with instance", "code": 400}}

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: I have problem with adding IP too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the 'Allocate IP to project' menu under the Security Tab first ?
If you have a floating IP available it should be connected to the instance you've created using the Associate IP -Action under the Security/Floating IP's. Remember to also allocate and connect the keys and open relevant ports as described here: http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/poi-data-provider/creating-instances
There has been some resource (floating IPs) limitations in the FILAB cloud servers so this may be also the reason if you have followed all the above.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there seems to be some problems with the POI GE image in the Fiware Cloud. Currently a working choice is to start an Ubuntu 14.04 image and install the POI GE according to http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/POI_Data_Provider_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide .